# I have a problem when using ubuntu 20.04, my wifi driver is qualcomm atheros QCA9377

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, atheros

My wifi driver is Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377, my laptop is Acer Aspire-E5-475.

My driver can't read the existing wifi connection. I think it's because it's blocked by the kernel.

[This is my wifi log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dmhqQcP6FheTr4Y3bN-uf6s7yOGE1g9S/view)

Can anyone help?

Comment: Hello I ran in the same issue, you can try this https://github.com/satishbabariya/qualcomm-atheros-QCA9377-wireless-patch I don't try it yet cause I downgrade my distro to 18.04 (Everything works perfect here) But this looks promissing

Comment: Thanks @PaoloDonatoNavarro, worked great for me